# Does downloading files and writing in streaming byte mode create two requests in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

Say I have the below function. (Sorry if I included too much.)

```py
@backoff.on_exception(
    backoff.expo,
    Exception,
    max_tries=10,
    factor=3600,
)
@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=10, period=60)
def download_file(url: str, filename: str, speedlimit: bool) -> requests.Response:
    """Download PDF files."""
    response = requests.get(url, headers=pdf_headers, stream=True, timeout=None)
    response.raise_for_status()
    if response.status_code != 200:
        response.close
        raise Exception

    else:
        fin = f"{config.Paths.pdf_path}{filename}.pdf"
        with tqdm.wrapattr(
            open(fin, "wb"),
            "write",
            total=int(response.headers.get("content-length", 0)),
        ) as fout:
            try:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8):
                    fout.write(chunk)
                    if speedlimit:
                        time.sleep(0.000285)  # Limits bandwith to ~20kB/s
                time.sleep(random.uniform(6, 7.2))

            except Exception:
                fout.flush()
                response.close

    return response
```

Does separating the response code check and adding stream, instead of doing it in one single shot, cause two requests instead of a single one?

I would think not, given the connection should already remain active (`pdf_headers = {"Connection": "keep-alive"}`) from the `requests.get()`. But I am troubleshooting rate limiting and seeing what I feel is a really low rate limit (less than 10 calls a minute), possibly even less than 500 calls an hour. Unfortunately, it's a government (state) website (IIS/ASP) that doesn't send retry-after headers with a 429 status code. And no rate limit listed in their robots.txt. (TY for making my job harder, government IT people.)

I am not using threading/multi-processing. So I know it's not an issue with multiple calls to a single server.

Comment: You are imposing artificial rate limiting, and doing such can cause a myriad of issues. In my opinion you should just make the request asynchronous, don't use the `stream` option since you are attempting to write the result to a file, and instead wait until the entire result is available instead of doing somewhat arbitrary `sleep` calls within your file I/O

Comment: @h0r53 so ditch the progress bars that requires chunking? And "somewhat arbitrary" sleep calls? The one sleep call is to limit bandwidth downloading that file (only way to do it in Python, yes?) And why use async, when the requests are all going to the same server? The second sleep call is to space out the requests so they aren't back to back to back, then a long sleep during the rate limiting.

Comment: @h0r53 Side note: is the backoff library no longer a thing because it's "artificial rate limiting"? Shall I ditch that and just keep hitting the server's 429 and be confused with a DDoS? We aren't just talking a few files here that I can just send 10 simultaneous file requests for. We are talking pdf files in the few dozen thousands.

Comment: @h0r53 also, NOT using stream can case RAM issues. There's reasons why that streaming option exists. I don't exactly have the funding for a server with a ton of ram and this isn't the only scraper running that downloads. Granted, maybe a moot point since the PDF files are relatively small. 

I would appreciate if you actually answered the question. Is it one request or two? I didn't ask to code review the function.

And functions that rate limit are common practice, yes? So what "myriad of issues" are we talking about? Being confused with a DDoS is a MAJOR issue I do not want to deal with.

Comment: The bandwidth limitations are imposed at a much lower level than your Python script. Having the file I/O portion perform more slowly will not affect bandwidth limitations related to the remote service or your network adapters. What happens when you make a single request instead of multiple? Does it go through successfully? If so then again, the bandwidth limitations and DDOS prevention are put in place through the remote service, and *slowing down how fast you write the results to a file will not truly address the issue*. The issue is likely how fast you make the requests themselves.

Comment: @h0r53 fair point on the file I/O, but since it's in streaming mode, the server only sends that fast on their bandwidth end. I put that there just to be even more friendly to the server given the nature of this scraper.

Comment: @h0r53 And I know it's about how fast I make the requests, which is why I am rate limiting on my end. Artificial limiting that you said creates a "myriad of issues." Your suggestion was to asyc. That doesn't slow down the requests. If anything, it jumbles them together and makes getting 429 responses even more likely. Maybe 500 calls per hour and 10 calls a minute is typical of a gov website. I can live with that. But at least I know the slow request rate is just a way conservative thing on the gov end. Or, if it's two requests and not one, then their limit is actually 1000 calls an hour.

Comment: This would be a non issue if they put their limits in their robots.txt or sent a retry-after header like a normal human being. But they don't. So ya gotta "hammer" the server to figure what they are. In the meantime, the other guy on the other end thinks you're a DDoS, regardless if you're sending a custom user agent identifying yourself or not. I've even sent an email asking and telling them what I was doing. No response.

Comment: And removing that file I/O restriction still leaves us with the rate and limit question. So not even relevant to the discussion at hand.

Comment: I suggested making the requests async because network requests are already asynchronous in nature, and since it seemed like you were aiming for optimizations, an asynchronous request would allow you to make requests without blocking the main thread. If this isn't particularly of value in your case then synchronous requests are fine. *"... Removing that file I/O restriction still leaves us with the rate and limit question."* - agreed. That is my point. Regardless of what you are doing to slow down the File I/O, you can still be rate limited on a request basis.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only solution you can likely implement in your code is to simply throttle how frequently you make the requests themselves, not how fast the data transfer occurs. The bandwidth limitation should be imposed on how often you call `requests.get` and not how often you call `fout.write(chunk)`.

Comment: @h0r53 I already know I need to limit the requests. That's why I am limiting the requests and troubleshooting 429 response codes. But I found it odd that a government server would be limiting their side to under 10 requests a minute and/or 500 per hour. Which is around the request rate I am at now and still getting sporadic 429's. Thus the question is the way I am doing it two requests or one? Which STILL hasn't been answered.  Sync requests are fine for what I am doing given that the rate limitation on their end isn't enough to be beneficial to use threading.

Comment: @h0r53 The file I/O limit thing was only to be nice on the sever while downloading repeatedly, for hours, days, and months on end. Given that I have to wait nearly 5 to 10 seconds (or more) between requests anyway, there's no need to be at full speed. Albeit, full speed here affects my other scripts too. And I would rather not develop an entire Kubernetes cluster (yet) and limit bandwidth that way. So that was reason #2 for the download speed limit.  I still want to know if my 10 in 60 is really 10 in 60 or 20 in 60. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: All that said, if I wanted to go faster than the server would allow me, I would simply go through multiple VPNs and then thread with 10-20 different sessions (async) and change the user agent to a normal (random) user agent instead of a personalized one identifying myself and the media (press) company this is for. But that would be a tad bit unethical and a borderline DDoS attack. :)

Comment: "Does separating the response code check and adding stream, instead of doing it in one single shot, cause two requests instead of a single one?" No. Invoking the `download_file` function (as defined) a single time will only result in a single HTTP request being made; though the response may come back in chunks.